# Iterating through a FC and clipping by muliple areas of interest

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I know how to build a model to iterate through a FC and clip that FC to ONE specific AOI, but is there a way (model or script) to iterate through that same FC but clip it to 35 different AOIs? I would prefer to not have to input the clip features 35 times but there might not be a way around that.

Comment: So do you mean you would want 2 iterators?  One iterator to pass in each feature from your feature class (the one you want to clip) and another one to pass in the 35 features from your clipping feature class?  Or are the AOI's all in different feature classes?

Answer (score 1):

If the 35 AOI's are 35 polygons in a single dataset then you iterate through these using the [Feature Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) iterator. The output of this would be your clipping layer.

Comment: I should have added more to the question. My FC does not have the AOI Field in the attributes. I have the AOIs in a separate FC so there is no way to iterate through that field. The field I want to iterate through is a "yes or no" filed. So I want the model to iterate through that field retain the "yes" and then clip those to the individual AOI's. So to clarify Interate through Yes field and clip to 35 individual AOIs (which is a completely separate FC and cant be iterated through in the model)?

Comment: Please update your question with this important information and I will delete my answer which is not valid.